# Adding discounts to shipping in magento

Tags: php, javascript, api, magento

I was wondering if anyone here has ever added an automatic discount to a shipping method in magento before. FedEx is the only company I ship with, but I have 3 different methods of FedEx. I want to add a discount to 2 of the 3 methods, and display these discounts at the method selection screen automatically at checkout(to make it seem like they are getting a deal with the higher priority shipping I suppose?). I found which file displays the methods, but I don't think this is the file I need:
template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml

Does anyone know which file these are displayed in so that I can slash out the real price, and add the discounted price bellow it? I suppose I could change the shipping price by just subtracting from the variable price, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this thread for adding custom discount price but its not related to any of shipping method price calculation, its might helpful, as its helped me well..

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total